# Filtering a column in a Spark Dataframe to find percentage of each element

Tags: python, filtering, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter a column in a Spark Dataframe with pyspark, I want to know which records represents 10% or less than the total column,

For example I have the following column entitled "Animal" in my DataFrame :

**Animal**

- Cat
- Cat
- Dog
- Dog
- Cat
- Cat
- Dog
- Dog
- Cat
- Rat

To find the record " Rat ", I tried

```
df.filter(df.groupBy("Animal").count() <= 0.1 * df.select("Animal").count()).collect()
```

and I got the following error " TypeError : condition should be string or column"

How can I find the records that represent less than 10% ?

PS : Would it be simpler in SQL ?

Something like :

```
result = spark.sql("SELECT Animal, COUNT(ANIMAL) FROM Table HAVING COUNT(Animal) < 0.1 * COUNT(Animal))
```

I know it is a simple operation but I just can't figure out how to code the 
10% of total part.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to count the total and in a second step use it to filter.

In condensed code (pyspark, spark 2.0):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df=sqlContext.createDataFrame([['Cat'],['Cat'],['Dog'],['Dog'],
    ['Cat'],['Cat'],['Dog'],['Dog'],['Cat'],['Rat']],['Animal'])
total=df.count()
result=(df.groupBy('Animal').count()
    .withColumn('total',F.lit(total))
    .withColumn('fraction',F.expr('count/total'))
    .filter('fraction>0.1'))
result.show()
```

Gave result:

```
+------+-----+-----+--------+
|Animal|count|total|fraction|
+------+-----+-----+--------+
|   Dog|    4|   10|     0.4|
|   Cat|    5|   10|     0.5|
+------+-----+-----+--------+
```

To filter your initial set:

```
filtered=df.join(result,df.Animal==result.Animal,'leftsemi')
filtered.show()
```

The 'leftsemi' join keeps the records in df that have a matching key in result